# The use of "take", "take back", "have back" and "get back" in context

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

Let's say my tablet stopped working and I took it to a rapair shop and said it would be fixed in three days. After three days I came back and what do I say to the shop assistant to tell them that I want my tablet back? Which ones of the following sentences sound the most natural?

> Can I **take** my tablet please?
>
> Can I **take** my tablet **back** please?
>
> Can I **have** my tablet **back** please?
>
> Can I **get** my tablet **back** please?

If none of them sounds natural, then what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: I'd be more likely to say 'Is my tablet fixed?'.

Comment: Yes, if you know that it is fixed (they told you that it woulf be ready in three days) which ones are fine?

Comment: To my British ear all of those sound slightly rude.  I think we would normally say something more euphemistic like "Is my tablet ready?" even if we 'know' it is.  Or else something like "Can I collect my tablet please?" or "I've come to pick up my tablet".  However, "can I get" seems to be a standard construction in American English customer service parlance, so perhaps they would sound fine to some people.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu - much though I have railed against people saying 'can I get...', more and more, I _find myself saying it!_. It's just a ritual polite prelude to issuing a request, and there's no need to waste everybody's time saying 'Good morning, Miss. I wonder if my tablet apparatus has been restored to working order?'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - yes, I suggested "Can I collect" as preferable to "Can I get", but I can think of a few schoolteachers who would still have recoiled at that, insisting upon "May I...", which to me sounds a bit datedly formal.  Language never stands still...!

Comment: Is this question really about the grammar of these particular phrases, or about what is actually said in this scenario? Because I wouldn't really ask a question like this. Instead I'd say something like "Hi, I'm [NAME HERE], I dropped my tablet off last week and they said it would be ready today"

Comment: As @Deolater and others have said, these are unlikely ways to tell a shop clerk that you want to collect your repaired devise.  But they are all (perhaps except the first) good ways to ask for your tablet back if you've let someone borrow or look at it.